# Como alterar a ordem da array? discord.js

Tags: javascript

Este é um código para fazer uma log do canal. Basicamente o que eu fiz foi criar uma array com todas as mensagens e formatar para que fique desta forma: *Membro#0000: (mensagem)*. Só que quando eu imprimo isso no console, ou em qualquer outro local, as mensagens vem de cabeça para baixo. Por exemplo, a última mensagem dita é a primeira a ser mostrada. Eu quero que a última mensagem dita seja a última mensagem da log, como faço isso (inverter a ordem)?

[image: Código]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Utilizando a função **reverse** do javascript:

```
messages
     .array()
     .reverse()
     .map(msg => console.log(`${msg.author.tag}: ${msg.content}`));
```

**Observação:** A *var arr* não está sendo lida em nenhum lugar e está dentro do escopo do **forEach** mesmo não pegando nada dele. É melhor declarar ela fora deste escopo.